# Parse Date from String does not work on IOS 12.4

Tags: ios, swift

I have used a Date Helper extension on the following site: https://github.com/melvitax/DateHelper
.I also try another pod framework: `SwiftDate`
.But those seems not working.
The Date is parsed from String always return nil.
Note, the code always works with versions which less than 12.4

.Here is my code:

`let expiredDate = Date(fromString: expired, format: .custom("yyyyMMddHHmmss"))`

===> expiredDate always return nil
.The expired = "20190701142359"

Ps: this is my first question, not get used to editing the post. sorry for any inconvenience

Comment: I tried your code let expiredDate = Date(fromString: "20190701142359", format: .custom("yyyyMMddHHmmss")) it works, don't see any problem. framework version 4.2.7

Answer (score 1):

Your date string is missing a leading 0 for hour

Try the following:

```
let d = DateFormatter()
d.dateFormat = "yyyyMMddHHmmss"

let s = d.date(from: "20190701014235")
```

output:

```
Optional(2019-07-01 01:42:35 +0000)
```

Comment: Have your IOS upgrade to 12.4 yet? Actually, it turns out the problem is my device locale and format date time. If my device set to English, it shouldn't need format 24-Hour, while Vietnam it should set to 24-Hour